# Performance testing a .NET smart client application (.NET ClickOnce technology)

Tags: .net, clickonce, performance-testing

What is the experience running performance tests for a ClickOnce application?

I have engaged with a vendor who had trouble setting up their toolset with our software because it is smart client based. They are understandably more geared toward purely browser-based applications.

What vendors could be recommended who use industry standard tools such as [LoadRunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_LoadRunner) (which I assume can handle the smart client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using a company with a tool called Web Performance (http://www.webperformanceinc.com).

Answer (score 1):

Is your smart client calling into a web service?  If so then the vendor should be able to use the web services to set up tests.

If the architecture of the application means you are hitting a database directly then you would need to set up soem kind of UI tests, Integration tests can be helpful here as well and maybe profile the database to ensure there are no bottleneccks there.

Comment: It is, but the web service calls are initiated by user interaction with the system. So we're trying to generate the load by way of the front end interface. We could script out the interactions, or build a purely browser-based UI for the vendors tools to call into, but we're running a little low on time :-)

Comment: There is no need you should be able to catch the XML that is getting sent up to the web services, have a look at Fiddler it is a Microsoft  utility that catches all HTTP traffic this means your requests to the web service will be captured, the tool you are working with should be able to spit XML directly at the services.